# The significance of the string immediately after query type (query / mutation) GraphQL

Tags: graphql, graphql-js

I was wondering what the significance of the string that follows the query type, in this case "ProvisionQueues", it seems removing this from the string doesn't affect anything - is it just for logging or something. meta data?

```
mutation ProvisionQueues {
 createQueue(name: "new-queue") {
    url
  }
}
```

Answer (score 20, accepted):

That string is the **operation name**. If you don't specify a name, the operation is known as an *anonymous operation*. When practical I like to always specify an operation name though, because it makes it easier for doing things like reading stack traces.

> it seems removing this from the string doesn't affect anything

You can only use an anonymous operation when you are performing a single operation. For instance, the following results in an error:

```
query {
  user(id: 1) {
    name
  }
}

query {
  user(id: 2) {
    name
  }
}
```

The error:

```
"message": "This anonymous operation must be the only defined operation."
```

If you want to learn more, you can check out [the GraphQL spec](https://spec.graphql.org/October2021/#sec-Anonymous-Operation-Definitions):

> If a document contains only one operation, that operation may be unnamed or represented in the shorthand form, which omits both the query keyword and operation name. Otherwise, if a GraphQL query document contains multiple operations, each operation must be named.

Answer (score 0):

Adding to @Eric's answer with another example.

```
query allNotifications {
  notifications {
    success
    errors
    notifications {
      id
      title
      description
      attachment
      createdAt
    }
  }
}    ​
​
query {
  users {
    errors
    success
    users {
      id
      fullName
    }
  }
}
```

Notice above that the users query has no **operation name**. This can be resolved as below.
​

```
query allUsers {
  users {
    errors
    success
    users {
      id
      fullName
      mohalla
    }
  }
}
```